# OpenPopUpPage resize

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, modal-dialog, application-pages, size

I am using a SharePoint 2013 On Prem Server and want to show a Modal Dialog in an application page.

I use: OpenPopUpPage(url, callback); 
This way the Dialog sizes to its content and everything is fine. Except when the aspx Page, which is the content of the Dialog, resizes after the dialog has been initialized.

can somebody give me a hint, how to resize the dialog when the content size changes?

best regards
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use function **SP.UI.ModalDialog.get_childDialog().autoSize()** in modal dialog page.

Find more details [here](http://chadschroeder.blogspot.ru/2012/10/sharepoint-2010-easy-dynamic-resize-of.html).